# How to get a Channel ID of a user message?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm coding a Discord Bot and I want to know how to get the channel ID from a message by any User.

I actually want to make a Text machine command. It leaves a message to a User when they are AFK or offline. When they come back and message in any of the channels in the server, the bot sends the message to them immediately to the same channel.

```
@client.command()
async def txt(ctx, receiver: discord.Member, *, message):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    def check(message: discord.Message):
        return message.author == receiver
    newembed = discord.Embed (title='On-Message Scheduled', description=f'Message will be delivered to the receiver as soon as he messages. \n Message: `{message}` \n to **{receiver}**')
    channel = await ctx.message.author.create_dm()
    x = await channel.send(embed=newembed)
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check = check)
    await ctx.send(f'TEXT MACHINE \n **{ctx.message.author}:** `{message}`\n for {receiver.mention}')
    await x.add_reaction('✅')
```

This actually works to some extent. But the problem is if I do, let's say `>txt @User#1234 this is a message` command on Channel 1, and the User messages on Channel 2, the bot sends the message to Channel 1, but I want the bot to send the message to the channel the User messaged.

Help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple, just don't use ctx.send, but use msg.channel.send. So the second line from end will look like this:

```
await msg.channel.send(f'TEXT MACHINE \n **{ctx.message.author}:** `{message}`\n for {receiver.mention}')
```